# Запрос для вставки данных в таблицу только в некоторые столбцы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите, в случае если у меня есть таблица из 4 столбцов (допустим, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`), причем в столбцах `a` и `b` уже есть данные, и я хочу вставить данные только в столбцы `c` и `d`, на основе пересечения вставляемых значений в столбце `а`, как мне это сделать? Мне особо не нравится, как сформулирован вопрос, но по-другому не получается, поэтому я проиллюстрирую:
в таблицу такого вида я хочу добавить значение `ccc` для столбца `c` и значение `ddd` для столбца `d`

```
a   b   c   d
aaa bbb null null
```

таким образом должна получиться таблица:

```
a   b   c   d
aaa bbb ccc ddd
```

Написал такой запрос, `insert into table(a, c, d) values ('aaa', 'ccc', 'ddd') on conflict(a) do update set c='ccc', d='ddd'`, но postgres ругается на то, что я не указал столбец `b`, соответственно он туда пытается вставить `null`, и получает ошибку из-за ограничения на невозможность вставки `null` в столбец `b`.

Comment: Вы ОБЯЗАНЫ указать в INSERT столбец `b` и  значение для него, если он определён как NOT NULL и не имеет DEFAULT значения. И это не лечится.

Comment: @Akina, тогда как мне указать, что в столбец b ничего вставлять не надо?

Comment: НИКАК. По-моему, это очевидно. У Вас проблема с первой частью запроса, с INSERT. не надо кивать на ON CONFLICT, в момент обнаружения ошибки до него дело ещё не дошло.

Comment: @Akina, тогда что же мне делать? И я не киваю на on conflict, мне понятно, что проблема в insert. Просто может есть способ указать, например, использовать для вставки в столбец b те же значения, которые в нем уже хранятся?

Comment: Думается мне вам вовсе insert не нужен, это вы так странно пытаетесь сделать update.

Comment: При вставке - вставляется НОВАЯ запись. О каких "уже хранятся" может идти речь, если запись только сейчас вставляется?

Comment: @Мелкий да мне тоже кажется, что ему нужен тупой ```update table set c='ccc', d='ddd' where a='aaa';```...

Comment: Да, вы оба правы, простой update помог. Большое спасибо.

Comment: @Мелкий Хотя на самом деле вопрос имеет смысл - если речь идёт о массированном update кучи записей одним запросом. Но всё равно - прописывать значения надо для всех NOT NULL non-DEFAULD полей.